# Warum das Relativpronom in Singular im Satz »...für alle Gerichte, bei der ...«?

Tags: relative-clause

Ich glaube Folgenden Satz gelesen zu haben:

> »Festkochende Kartoffeln eignen sich für alle Gerichte, bei **der** die Kartoffel in Form bleiben soll.«[image]

Ist der korrekt? Ist **denen** statt **der** erlaubt? Funktioniert dann *alle* als wäre es in Singular?

Comment: I think this is definitely a mistake. ‘Gericht’ is neuter – so it would have to be ‘bei *dem*’ in the very least. That’s also not correct, though. As you say, ‘denen’ is needed.

Comment: The end of all days is close. Food sellersstart issuing misspelled labels!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nein, der Satz ist nicht korrekt.
Es muss

> Festkochende Kartoffeln eignen sich für alle Gerichte, bei **denen** die Kartoffel in Form bleiben soll.

"Denen" bezieht sich auf "alle Gerichte", es ist Plural.